# Terraform `name` vs `self_link` in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

In GCP, when using Terraform, I see I can use `name` attribute as well as `self_link`. So, I am wondering if there are cases where I must use any of those.

For example:

```
resource "google_compute_ssl_policy" "custom_ssl_policy" {
  name            = "my-ssl-policy"
  profile         = "MODERN"
  min_tls_version = "TLS_1_1"
}
```

this object, then can be referred as:

```
ssl_policy = google_compute_ssl_policy.custom_ssl_policy.name
```

and

```
ssl_policy = google_compute_ssl_policy.custom_ssl_policy.self_link
```

I know that `object.name` returns the Terraform object name, and `object.self_link` returns GCP's resources's URI.

I have tried with several objects, and it works with both attributes, so I want to know if this is trivial or there are situations where I should use one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the definition from the official documentation:

> Nearly every GCP resource will have a name field. They are used as a
> short way to identify resources, and a resource's display name in the
> Cloud Console will be the one defined in the name field.
>
> When linking resources in a Terraform config though, you'll primarily
> want to use a different field, the self_link of a resource. Like name,
> nearly every resource has a self_link. They look like:

https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/foo/zones/us-central1-c/instances/terraform-instance

> A resource's self_link is a unique reference to that resource. When
> linking two resources in Terraform, you can use Terraform
> interpolation to avoid typing out the self link!

Reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started

One example, I can deploy two cloud functions with the same name/same project but in different regions. In this case, if you had to reference both resources in Terraform code, you would be better by using the self_link since it's a unique URI.

Answer (score 0):

In addittion to CaioT's answer, `self-link` is used to reference values in the outputs.tf file.

As an example, if you wanted to know the minimum tls version before applying your terraform config, you can use outputs to display these values in the console. This ensures you can confirm values before applying them in terraform.

// the code below outputs the value of the minimum TLS version to the console // when you run `terraform apply`

```
output "current_min_tls_version" {
    value = google_compute_ssl_policy.custom_ssl_policy.min_tls_version
}
```

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/gcp-get-started/google-cloud-platform-outputs

Comment: I doubt `google_compute_ssl_policy.custom_ssl_policy.min_tls_version` will end up being a `self-link` of anything. Probably something like `1.1`.